# Rich-Text-Editing Rails-Based CMS

Tags: ruby-on-rails, content-management-system

I am searching for a rails-based CMS that provide rich text editing feature (i.e., I need an interface very similar to that of Wordpress where you can easily style up your static pages and upload pictures without knowing any css or html) AND easy to be dropped into an existing rails application.

Camtose, RadiantCMS and few other ones did not seem to offer the rich interface I was looking for. RefineryCMS had a conflict with my existing user authentication and I did not really find a solution to it. I am just wondering if there are any Rails-based CMSes that can meet my needs.

Please advise if you know of any such Rails-based CMS.

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 3):

Hey http://refinerycms.com now uses AuthLogic and shouldn't conflict. If you've got some specific issues feel free to post them on the Refinery CMS Google Groups: http://groups.google.com/group/refinery-cms

Comment: Official release of Rails 3 support for RefineryCMS was today: refinerycms.com/blog/refinery-cms-supports-rails-3

Answer (score 1):

ubiquo might be for you - http://www.ubiquo.me/ - it requires a bit of programming to get running, but not too much - how good are your rails skills?

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I will take a look. I have experience with various plugins so I will give this a shot!

Comment: @stephenmurdoch, have you used ubiquo yourself? Good, bad, etc.?

Comment: hi Daniel, I've used ubiquo and I liked it but I didn't persevere with it as I prefer to use ActiveScaffold as I've got it working the way I want it to

Answer (score 1):

Since you are looking for the ability to generate rich text, which is pretty separate from the requirements of a CMS, maybe you are looking for an editor, and not specifically a cms.

Wordpress (as well as google and many others) uses TinyMCE which is a javascript rich text text editor. There would be nothing to prevent you from using TinyMCE in any application framework,including rails, or as a drop-in replacement for the existing editor in Radiant.

Take a look here:
http://tinymce.moxiecode.com/

and easy setup with jquery here:
http://tinymce.moxiecode.com/examples/example_23.php

Answer (score 0):

I've used [CKEditor](http://ckeditor.com/) with great success in a few Rails projects.  It's image/file upload ability is really nice too. It kinda gives you that Wordpress media library browsing functionality to re-embed images/files back into the content body.